# Best approach for performance when filtering for permissions in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on an application where a user can have access to many forms through many different scenarios. I am trying to build the approach with the best performance when returning an index of forms to the user.

A user can have access to forms via the following scenarios:

- Owns Form
- Team owns Form
- Has permissions to a group that owns a Form
- Has permissions to a team that owns a Form
- Has permission to a Form

As you can see there are 5 possible ways that the user can access a form. My problem is how to i most efficiently return an array of the accessible forms to the user.

Form Policy:

I have tried to get all of the Forms from model and then filter the forms by the form policy. This seems to be a performance issue as on each filter iteration the form gets passed through a contains() eloquent method 5 times as shown below. The more forms in the database means this becomes slower.

```
FormController@index

public function index(Request $request)
{
   $forms = Form::all()
      ->filter(function($form) use ($request) {
         return $request->user()->can('view',$form);
   });
}
```

```
FormPolicy@view

public function view(User $user, Form $form)
{
   return $user->forms->contains($form) ||
      $user->team->forms->contains($form) ||
      $user->permissible->groups->forms($contains);
}
```

Although the above method works it is a performance bottle neck.

From what i can see my following options are:

- FormPolicy filter (current approach)
- Query all permissions (5) and merge into single collection
- Query all identifiers for all permissions (5), then query the Form model using the identifiers in an *IN()* statement

My question:

Which method would provide the best performance and is there any other option which would provide better performance?

Comment: you can also make a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) approach to link if the user can access the form

Comment: What about creating a table specifically for querying user form permissions? The `user_form_permission` table containing just the `user_id` and the `form_id`. This will make reading permissions a breeze, however updating permissions will be harder.

Comment: The problem with the user_form_permissions table is that we want to expand permissions to other entities which would then require a separate table for each entity.

Comment: My current approach and one that has provided the best performance is to query out the forms from each of the 5 methods and merge them into a single collection. The verdict seems to be get only what you need not everything and filter a large collection for best performance.

Comment: @Tim but that's still 5 queries. If this is just inside a protected member's area, might not be an issue. But if this is on a public facing URL that can get a lot of requests per second, i recon you would want to optimize this a bit. For performance reason, i would maintain a separate table (that i can cache) every time a form or team member is added or removed via model observers. Then, on every request, i would get that from cache. I find this question and problem very interesting and would love to know what others think too. This question deserve more votes and answers, started a bounty:)

Comment: You could consider having a [materialised view](https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) which you could refresh as a scheduled job. This way you can always have relatively up to date results quickly.

Comment: I think you want these to be always up2date. But, i like this approach. It could save this in 1 table, much smaller, and correctly indexed for the query. It could be a simple user_id + form_id row, indexed. It still has the burden to update this, but again, via model observers, keeping this updated could be done quite easily. The first goal here is to not repeat the same queries on every request. I like this more. @Tim, what you think?

Comment: I will assume that your scheme has foreign keys defined, right?

Comment: Would be worth considering caching too.

Answer (score 3):

I would look to do an SQL Query as that is going to perform much better than php

Something like this:

```
User::where('id', $request->user()->id)
    ->join('group_users', 'user.id', 'group_users.user_id')
    ->join('team_users', 'user.id', 'team_users.user_id',)
    ->join('form_owners as user_form_owners', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', 'form_owners.owner_id')
            ->where('form_owners.owner_type', User::class);
    })
    ->join('form_owners as group_form_owners', function ($join) {
        $join->on('group_users.group_id', 'form_owners.owner_id')
            ->where('form_owners.owner_type', Group::class);
    })
    ->join('form_owners as team_form_owners', function ($join) {
        $join->on('team_users.team_id', 'form_owners.owner_id')
           ->where('form_owners.owner_type', Team::class);
    })
    ->join('forms', function($join) {
        $join->on('forms.id', 'user_form_owners.form_id')
            ->orOn('forms.id', 'group_form_owners.form_id')
            ->orOn('forms.id', 'team_form_owners.form_id');
    })
    ->selectRaw('forms.*')
    ->get();
```

From the top of my head and untested this should get you all of the forms that are owned by the user, his groups and this teams.

It does not however look at the permissions of the user view forms in groups and teams.

I am not sure how you have your auth set up for this and so you would need to modify the query for this and any difference in your DB structure.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, the problem was not the query on how to get the data from the database. The problem is, how to get it efficiently every time, on every request, when the app has hundred of thousands of forms and lots of teams and members. Your joins have `OR` clauses in, which i suspect there are gonna be slow. So hitting this on every request will be insane i believe.

Comment: You might be able to get better speed with raw MySQL query or using some thing like views or procedures but you are going to have to do calls like this each time that you want the data. Caching of results might also help here.

Comment: While i'm thinking the only way to make this performant is caching, that comes at the cost of always maintaining this map every time a change is made. Imagine i create a new form, which, if a team is assigned to my account means thousands of users might get access to it. What's next? Re-cache a few thousand members policy?

Comment: There are cache solutions with lifetime (like laravel's cache abstractions), and you can also remove the cache indexes affected right after you do any change. The cache's a real game-changer if you use it correctly. How to configure the cache depends of the reads and updates of the data.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

The third option: `Query all identifiers for all permissions (5), then query the Form model using the identifiers in an IN() statement`

```
$teamMorphType  = Relation::getMorphedModel('team');
$groupMorphType = Relation::getMorphedModel('group');
$formMorphType  = Relation::getMorphedModel('form');

$permissible = [
    $teamMorphType  => [$user->team_id],
    $groupMorphType => [],
    $formMorphType  => [],
];

foreach ($user->permissible as $permissible) {
    switch ($permissible->permissible_type) {
        case $teamMorphType:
        case $groupMorphType:
        case $formMorphType:
            $permissible[$permissible->permissible_type][] = $permissible->permissible_id;
            break;
    }
}

$forms = Form::query()
             ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
             ->orWhereIn('id', $permissible[$fromMorphType])
             ->orWhereIn('team_id', $permissible[$teamMorphType])
             ->orWhereIn('group_id', $permissible[$groupMorphType])
             ->get();
```

## Long answer

On one hand, (almost) everything that you can do in code, is better performance-wise, than do it in queries.

On the other hand, getting more data from the database than necessary would be too much data already (RAM usage and so on).

From my perspective, you need something in between, and only you will know where would be the balance, depending on the numbers.

I would suggest running several queries, the last option you proposed (`Query all identifiers for all permissions (5), then query the Form model using the identifiers in an IN() statement`):

1. Query all identifiers, for all permissions (5 queries)
2. Merge all the forms results in memory, and get unique values `array_unique($ids)`
3. Query the Form model, using the identifiers in an IN() statement.

You can try the three options you proposed and monitor the performance, using some tool to run the query multiple times, but I am 99% sure that the last one will give you the best performance.

This may also change a lot, depending on which database are you using, but if we are talking about MySQL, for instance; In A very big query would use more database resources, which will not only spend more time than simple queries, but also will lock the table from writes, and this can produce deadlock errors (unless you use a slave server).

On the other side, if the number of forms ids is very big, you can have errors for too many placeholders, so you may want to chunk the queries in groups of, let's say, 500 ids (this depends a lot, as the  limit is in size, not in number of bindings), and merge the results in memory. Even if you don't get a database error, you may see a big difference in performance as well (I am still talking about MySQL).

---

## Implementation

I will assume that this is the database scheme:

```
users
  - id
  - team_id

forms
  - id
  - user_id
  - team_id
  - group_id

permissible
  - user_id
  - permissible_id
  - permissible_type
```

So permissible would be an already configured [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Therefore, the relations would be:

- Owns Form: `users.id <-> form.user_id`
- Team owns Form: `users.team_id <-> form.team_id`
- Has permissions to a group that owns a Form: `permissible.user_id <-> users.id && permissible.permissible_type = 'App\Team'`
- Has permissions to a team that owns a Form: `permissible.user_id <-> users.id && permissible.permissible_type = 'App\Group'`
- Has permission to a Form: `permissible.user_id <-> users.id && permissible.permissible_type = 'App\From'`

Simplify version:

```
$teamMorphType  = Relation::getMorphedModel('team');
$groupMorphType = Relation::getMorphedModel('group');
$formMorphType  = Relation::getMorphedModel('form');

$permissible = [
    $teamMorphType  => [$user->team_id],
    $groupMorphType => [],
    $formMorphType  => [],
];

foreach ($user->permissible as $permissible) {
    switch ($permissible->permissible_type) {
        case $teamMorphType:
        case $groupMorphType:
        case $formMorphType:
            $permissible[$permissible->permissible_type][] = $permissible->permissible_id;
            break;
    }
}

$forms = Form::query()
             ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
             ->orWhereIn('id', $permissible[$fromMorphType])
             ->orWhereIn('team_id', $permissible[$teamMorphType])
             ->orWhereIn('group_id', $permissible[$groupMorphType])
             ->get();
```

Detailed version:

```
// Owns Form
// users.id <-> forms.user_id
$userId = $user->id;

// Team owns Form
// users.team_id <-> forms.team_id
// Initialise the array with a first value.
// The permissions polymorphic relationship will have other teams ids to look at
$teamIds = [$user->team_id];

// Groups owns Form was not mention, so I assume there is not such a relation in user.
// Just initialise the array without a first value.
$groupIds = [];

// Also initialise forms for permissions:
$formIds = [];

// Has permissions to a group that owns a Form
// permissible.user_id <-> users.id && permissible.permissible_type = 'App\Team'
$teamMorphType = Relation::getMorphedModel('team');
// Has permissions to a team that owns a Form
// permissible.user_id <-> users.id && permissible.permissible_type = 'App\Group'
$groupMorphType = Relation::getMorphedModel('group');
// Has permission to a Form
// permissible.user_id <-> users.id && permissible.permissible_type = 'App\Form'
$formMorphType = Relation::getMorphedModel('form');

// Get permissions
$permissibles = $user->permissible()->whereIn(
    'permissible_type',
    [$teamMorphType, $groupMorphType, $formMorphType]
)->get();

// If you don't have more permissible types other than those, then you can just:
// $permissibles = $user->permissible;

// Group the ids per type
foreach ($permissibles as $permissible) {
    switch ($permissible->permissible_type) {
        case $teamMorphType:
            $teamIds[] = $permissible->permissible_id;
            break;
        case $groupMorphType:
            $groupIds[] = $permissible->permissible_id;
            break;
        case $formMorphType:
            $formIds[] = $permissible->permissible_id;
            break;
    }
}

// In case the user and the team ids are repeated:
$teamIds = array_values(array_unique($teamIds));
// We assume that the rest of the values will not be repeated.

$forms = Form::query()
             ->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
             ->orWhereIn('id', $formIds)
             ->orWhereIn('team_id', $teamIds)
             ->orWhereIn('group_id', $groupIds)
             ->get();
```

### Resources used:

Database performance:

- Queries to the database (excluding the user): **2**; one to get the permissible and another one to get the forms.
- **No joins!!**
- The minimum ORs possible (`user_id = ? OR id IN (?..) OR team_id IN (?...) OR group_id IN (?...)`.

PHP, in memory, performance:

- **foreach** looping the permissible with a **switch** inside.
- `array_values(array_unique())` to avoid repeating the ids.
- In memory, 3 arrays of ids (`$teamIds`, `$groupIds`, `$formIds`)
- In memory, relevant permissions eloquent collection (this can be optimised, if needed).

---

## Pros and cons

PROS:

- **Time**: The sum of times of single queries is less than the time of a big query with joins and OR.
- **DB Resources**: The MySQL resources used by a query with join and or statements, are bigger than the used by the sum of its separate queries.
- **Money**: Fewer database resources (processor, RAM, disc read, etc.), which are more expensive than PHP resources.
- **Locks**: In case you are not querying a read-only slave server, your queries will make fewer rows read locks (the read lock is shared in MySQL, so it won't lock another read, but it will block any write).
- **Scalable**: This approach allows you to make more performance optimizations such as chunk the queries.

CONS:

- **Code resources**: Making calculations in code, rather than in the database, will obviously consume more resources in the code instance, but especially in the RAM, storing the middle information. In our case, this would be just an array of ids, which shouldn't be a problem really.
- **Maintenance**: If you use Laravel's properties and methods, and you do any change in the database, it will be easier to update in code than if you make more explicit queries and processing.
- **Overkilling?**: In some cases, if the data is not that big, optimising the performance may be overkilling.

---

## How to measure performance

Some clues about how to measure the performance?

1. [Slow query logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/slow-query-log.html)
2. [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/analyze-table.html)
3. [SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-table-status.html)
4. [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html); [Extended EXPLAIN Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain-extended.html); [using explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/using-explain.html); [explain output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain-output.html)
5. [SHOW WARNINGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-warnings.html)

Some interesting profiling tools:

- [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)
- [Percona  Query Digest (pt-query-digest)](https://www.percona.com/)
- [log-top](http://julienpalard.github.io/logtop/)

Comment: What is that first line? It is almost always better performance wise to use a query, because running various loops or array manipulation in PHP is slower.

Comment: If you have a small database or your database machine is way more powerful than your code instance, or the database latency is very bad, then yes, MySQL is faster, but this is not usually the case.

Comment: When you optimize a database query, you need to consider the execution time, the number of rows returned, and most importantly, the number of rows examined. If Tim is saying that the queries are becoming slow, then I assume that the data is growing, and therefore the number of rows examined. Besides, the database is not optimized for processing as a programing language is.

Comment: But you don't need to trust me, you can run [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html), for your solution, then you can run it for my solution of simple queries, and see the difference, and then think if a simple `array_merge()` and `array_unique()` of a bunch of ids, would really slow down your process.

Comment: In 9 out of 10 cases the mysql database runs on the same machine that runs the code. The data layer is meant to be used for data retrieval and it is optimized for selecting pieces of data from large sets. I've yet to see a situation where a `array_unique()` is faster than a `GROUP BY`/`SELECT DISTINCT` statement.

Comment: First, I disagree, most of the PHP production web apps are in AWS, Digital Ocean, Docker containers, cPanel, and things alike. None of them shared the same (virtual) machine for both code and databases unless you do a bad use of them. And second, I never said anything about `GROUP BY/SELECT DISTINCT`, so I don't know what does it have anything to do with the subject that we are discussing.

Comment: Besides, if MySQL and php-fmt / php-cli shares the same machine, then, definitely, running functions, joins and merging is faster and uses fewer resources in PHP than in MySQL. Otherwise you could use MySQL [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/functions.html) and [procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/functions.html)...

Comment: I dont see how you cant fathom that a DB engine has probably worth of 10+ years of optimization. Aggregating, filtering and/or joining data belongs to the data layer. Please come up with a proper example that shows that processing is faster in PHP than in MySQL. I will then probably explain to you that your example is wrong.

Comment: Again, you don't need to trust me. Just try it, and you will see. I already explain you that MySQL is not a programming language, it is not optimise to process information, but to access it. A programming language is optimise to process the information, and leaves the data access to the database connections. Again, if you trust more in the processing in MySQL, then you can program on it, and just forget about programming languages, because as you said, it has more than 10 years optimising it, so why use anything else at all?

Comment: Besides: 1) he number of years that anything had in the market doesn't make it better or worse (it does the community, the stability, maturity, etc.). 2) PHP was created in 1994 (25 years ago), and is a higher level of C, which was created at the beginnings of the 70's (almost 40 years ago). 3) MariaDB is newer than MySQL, and more recommendable in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Lazy Collections for that (Laravel 6.x) and eager load the relationships before they are accessed.

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
   // Eager Load relationships
   $request->user()->load(['forms', 'team.forms', 'permissible.group']);
   // Use cursor instead of all to return a LazyCollection instance
   $forms = Form::cursor()->filter(function($form) use ($request) {
         return $request->user()->can('view', $form);
   });
}
```

```php
public function view(User $user, Form $form)
{
   return $user->forms->contains($form) ||
      $user->team->forms->contains($form) ||
      // $user->permissible->groups->forms($contains); // Assuming this line is a typo
      $user->permissible->groups->contains($form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you simply query the Forms you need, instead of doing `Form::all()` and then chaining a `filter()` function after it?

Like so:

```php
public function index() {
    $forms = $user->forms->merge($user->team->forms)->merge($user->permissible->groups->forms);
}
```

So yes, this does a few queries:

- A query for `$user`
- One for `$user->team`
- One for `$user->team->forms`
- One for `$user->permissible`
- One for `$user->permissible->groups`
- One for `$user->permissible->groups->forms`

However, the pro side is that you **no longer need to use the policy**, since you know all forms in the `$forms` parameter are allowed for the user.

So this solution will work for whatever amount of forms you have in the database.

> **A note on using `merge()`**
>
> `merge()` merges the collections, and will discard duplicate
>   form ids that it has already found. So if for some reason a form from the
>   `team` relation is also a direct relation to the `user`, it will only show once in the merged collection.
>
> This is because it is actually a
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` which has its own `merge()` function that checks for the Eloquent model ids. So you cant actually use this trick when merging 2 different collection contents like `Posts` and `Users`, because a user with id `3` and a post with id `3` will conflict in this case, and only the latter (the Post) will be found in the merged collection.

---

If you want it to be even faster, you should create a custom query using the DB facade, something along the lines of:

```php
// Select forms based on a subquery that returns a list of id's.
$forms = Form::whereIn(
    'id',
    DB::select('id')->from('users')->where('users.id', $user->id)
        ->join('teams', 'users.id', '=', 'teams.user_id')
        ...
)->get();
```

Your actual query is much bigger since you have so many relations.

The main performance improvement here comes from the fact that the heavy work (the subquery) completely bypasses the Eloquent model logic. Then all that is left to do is to pass the list of ids into the `whereIn` function to retrieve your list of `Form` objects.